# Numerical frameworks for solving completely arbitrary functio-differential equations?

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, functional-equations

Which numerical methods exist to solve (estimate) completely arbitrary equations with:

1. Constraints on definition and/or value space (boundary conditions for example)
2. Composition with arbitrary smooth functions
3. Differentiation and integration
4. Probabilistic constraints.

For example

$$\exp\left[i\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2\right]= \sin(x^2)$$
Subject to
$$\int_{y_{n}}^{y_{n+1}} f(x) dy = c_n$$

For prescribed $c_n$. The intent is in some sense a histogram integrating over slices of the value space.

**(this integral may not make much sense right now, but I am working on it.)**

Comment: Matlab, Numpy, blood, sweat and tears, maybe.

Comment: Yep, I guess those would be great choices of software to attempt to write one in. Not that it would be easy..